# Translate data.table syntax into dplyr syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I want to have the following code from `data.table` in a dplyr way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

Iris <- as.data.table(iris)

Iris[, .(m = mean(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width < 3])), Species]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width))
```

But I do not know where I can place my condition `Sepal.Width < 3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same way as in `data.table` or in `base R`, create the logical vector (`Sepal.Width < 3`), use that to subset the column with `[` and get the `mean` of the subset of values

```
library(dplyr)
Iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width <3]))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species        m
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa      2.60
#2 versicolor  2.61
#3 virginica   2.69
```

Comment: Oh. I could have come to that myself. How embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: @natej  Yes, that would make one more line of code but it is more clear.  Thanks , `filter(Sepal.Width <3) %>% summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width))`

Comment: This solution works just just as well for this question, but as a note a common dplyr way to subset values is typically `filter()`

Comment: @natej Maybe this is already what you're saying but `filter(cond) %>% summarise(x = mean(x))` is not equivalent to `summarise(x = mean(x[cond]))` since the condition might be met for zero rows in some groups. The latter is a more correct translation of the OP's DT code in that sense.